# "error occurred while loading or saving configuration information"

Tags: linux, unix, root, redhat

i have two accounts in my redhat instance. one is `ora112` user and other user is `root` user by default.

i have been updating `ora112` users `bashrc` file using root account, but i did change my command prompt to `ora112` before editing. this is what i did.

```
root$ su ora112
password: 
ora112$ vi ~.bashrc
```

but when doing that, i had logged into the system using `root` even thought command prompt is changed to ora112

but when i login to the system as ora112 , it gives me following screen.

[image]

could anybody help me to find what is going wrong here, thanks in advance for anyhelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su - ora112
```

"su - user" gives you the environment for the user "su user" does not